# HTML text in [text] when using amp-state

Tags: amp-html

I have a simple JSON file:

```
{
  "title": "Title here",
  "content": "<p>line 1<br/>line 2</p>"
}
```

That I reference using amp-state

```
<amp-state id="remoteContent" src="//mysite.local/json/remoteContent.json"></amp-state>
```

I am then binding the result of this into an HTML container.

```
<div class="title" [text]="remoteContent.title">

</div>

<div class="content" [text]="remoteContent.content">

</div>
```

My issue is the content text comes out literately, and doesn't render the actual HTML. Is there an equivalent of ASP.NET Razor syntax @HTML.Raw when using AMP?

I've tried encoding and escaping the HTML in the JSON file, but this doesn't work.

I know I might be able to achieve this using AMP-List and amp-mustache, however this adds extra containers which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: AMP do not allow to load data from json on load. The reason is to avoid the risk of unexpected content jumping. You can have a look at note here https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#a-simple-example

Comment: My example works so I can load json on load.. In fact, it took the basis from the link you shared.. My issue is it's loading the HTML with out actually applying it.. so I see the tags outputted.

Comment: ahh. I missed the bit about it not evaluating.. so indeed it seems what I want to do is not possible.

Comment: @mp3duck It is possible if you serve the json data from an API and render it using an `AMP-mustache` template inside an `amp-list`.

Comment: @ChrisAbyAntony- This is precisely the method I'll take - but I am not liking the extra containers that get rendered, but should be able to work around it..

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve your goal using amp-state because due to security reasons, binding to innerHTML is disallowed. for more information you can visit : [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind)

`[text]`  attribute for text elements only and use Node.textContent

The Node.textContent property represents the text content of a node and its descendants.

[For more infomation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

[Example of textContent and innerHTML](http://jsfiddle.net/t135afoz/)

```
<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("divA").textContent = "<b>This is some text</b>";
document.getElementById("divB").innerHTML = "<b>This is some text</b>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible right now as you're unable to bind to `innerHTML` with amp-bind per the specifications (See notes on binding [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind)).

Your best option would be to do something like this, or utilize [amp-mustache](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache) and [amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) like you mentioned as author written JavaScript expressions are not allowed.

**remoteContent State:**

```
{
  "title": "Title here",
  "item1": "Line 1"
  "item2": "Line 2"
  "item3": "Line 3"
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div>
  <p [text]="remoteContent.title"></p>
  <p [text]="remoteContent.item1"></p>
  <p [text]="remoteContent.item2"></p>
  <p [text]="remoteContent.item3"></p>
</div>
```