# How can I put HTML returned from my webservice into a div with amp-bind?

Tags: amp-html

How can I put the following HTML:

```html
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

into a div element?

If I do something like this:

```html
<div [text]="myHtmlText"></div>
```

I get my text as a plain HTML (because it appears in quotes),
and it is not rendered as a HTML list.

How can I do it, without using amp-mustache?

Comment: you can not render in [text], use amp-mustache: both link help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113635/5635098 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243684/display-raw-html-from-json-to-amp-page/53246476#53246476 . some tag of html does not allow

Comment: How can I use amp-mustache to use this HTML in multiple forms in a single page, rendered at once?